# Unknown error and logic error in c# program of extension methods

Tags: c#, syntax-error

this is my c# code. There is an error I don't know, I am an intermediate programmer. check the code pls -

I have been programming and I didn't understand extension methods completely. I don't know much namespaces, and I know that my code is a bit stupid in the first class, but I put it here so you can check it out why it doesn't work. The main questions for me are -

1. Why is there an error in the program?
2. Why doesn't my namespace of ExtensionMethods work? I have implemented it at the top of the code also. If I make the program class non-static, and I use the namespace ExtensionMethods as normally to implement the methods, why doesn't work?

and um... here is the error details given to me by Visual Studio IDE -

```
System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not 
execute.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
at 
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource 
resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
at ConsoleApp1.Program.JoinWords(String s) in
```

and this is the code -

```
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using ExtensionMethods;
    
    
    namespace ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static class TryExtensions
        {
            public static string JoinWords(this string s)
            {
                List<char> contents = new List<char>() { };
    
                foreach (char i in s)
                {
                    contents.Add(i);
                }
    
                foreach (char i in contents)
                {
                    if (i == ' ')
                    {
                        contents.Remove(i);
                    }
                }
    
                StringBuilder somestring = new StringBuilder();
    
                foreach (char i in contents)
                {
                    somestring.Append(i);
                }
    
                s = somestring.ToString();
    
                return s;
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {
        static class Program
        {
    
            public static string JoinWords(this string s)
            {
                List<char> contents = new List<char>() { };
    
                foreach (char i in s)
                {
                    contents.Add(i);
                }
    
                foreach (char i in contents)
                {
                    if (i == ' ')
                    {
                        contents.Remove(i);
                    }
                }
    
                StringBuilder somestring = new StringBuilder();
    
                foreach (char i in contents)
                {
                    somestring.Append(i);
                }
    
                s = somestring.ToString();
    
                return s;
            }
            static void Main(String[] args )
            {
                string sayHello = "Hello World, i really hope all spaces will be removed from this, and this sentence will be a joined one word";
    
                sayHello = JoinWords(sayHello);
    
                Debug.WriteLine(sayHello);
            }
        }
    }
```

right so this was the code

1. Why is there an error in the program?
2. Why doesn't my namespace of ExtensionMethods work? I have implemented it at the top of the code also.

Comment: Share the Error

Comment: i have shared the error by editing the question please check

Comment: Are you writing that extension method for experimentation? Because if not, you could just do `sayHello = sayHello.Replace(" ", "");`

Answer (score 1):

An extension method is treated as if it was a method of the class (the `string` class in this case).
So replace

```
sayHello = JoinWords(sayHello);
```

with

```
sayHello = sayHello.JoinWords();
```

In others words a `string` extension method should be treated exactly like any other `string` method.

You can remove JoinWords() from class Program.

Having said that, you have a runtime error caused by modifying `contents` inside the `for each i in contents` loop. You're not allowed to delete items in a list while you're iterating through that list with a `foreach`. The usual way to handle this is by saving the index values you want to delete in the `foreach` loop and then doing the `remove` in another loop.

Caution: Suppose you want to delete indexes i1, i2, i3. When you remove index i1, all following items are shifted left so you need to subtract 1 from i2 and i3. Then when you delete i2, you need to again subtract 1 from i3.

Comment: No, the error is different. the error is --  System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.JoinWords(String s)

Comment: @VKGautam See the duplicate.